# Override config settings

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

I have a config file that is used in several projects, `general.config`, looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
   <add key="mykey1" value="myvalue1"/>    
   <add key="mykey2" value="myvalue2"/>
</appSettings>
```

In one of the projects, I need to override one of the two settings. So the `app.config` of this project looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="general.config">
    <remove key="mykey1"/>
    <add key="mykey1" value="anothervalue"/>
    <add key="mykey3" value="myvalue3"/>
  </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

But `remove` is not working here. How can I override `mykey1` without breaking `mykey2`? `add` works in this case. I can get `myvalue3` from `ConfigurationManager`.

EDIT: `general.config` is copied to output folder automatically when compiling. Don't worry about the path issue. Currently I got:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey1"] 
     //I got "myvalue1", but I want "anothervalue" here
     //that is, this item is "overrided", just like virtual methods in C#
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey2"] 
     //this setting will not be modified, currently it works fine
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey3"]   //good
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `config` transformation?

Comment: Hope the Path specified via `file` is relative to the config else it would be ignored

Comment: @V4Vendetta：You are correct. The general.config is copied to output folder while compiling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms228154(v=vs.100)) helps to answer the question:

> You can use the file attribute to
> specify a configuration file that
> provides additional settings or
> overrides the settings that are
> specified in the appSettings element.
> You can use the file attribute in
> source control team development
> scenarios, such as when a user wants
> to override the project settings that
> are specified in an application
> configuration file. Configuration
> files that are specified in a file
> attribute must have the appSettings
> element rather than configuration
> element as the root node.

So, the settings in your `general.config` will override items in `app.config`. This is the opposite of what you want (to have `app.config` items override `general.config` items). You will have to resolve this issue in C# code (it will inevitably look ugly).

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the `file` attribute to load common settings with an expectation that keys added directly to the `<appSettings>` element would override those common settings is understandable, but unfortunately that is not how it works.

Microsoft's intention was for the `file` attribute to load common settings that override the individual application's settings.

This is discussed in some detail in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx)

To overcome this problem, we very occasionally declare base settings in the common file, and then appropriately named overrides in the application configuration. However this does require additional code which is a bit ugly. e.g.

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSG_QUEUE_PROVIDER_OVERRIDE"]
    ?? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSG_QUEUE_PROVIDER"]
    ?? "ActiveMQ";
```

---

```
<appSettings file="common.config"> 
    <!-- Override the common values -->
    <add key="MSG_QUEUE_PROVIDER_OVERRIDE" value="RabbitMQ"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements are changed from the child and what i mean by that is currently your app.config is the parent file and the values are replaced by the ones existing in General.config

Since you are using `remove` in the parent file what its effectively doing is removing the element you specify in app.config but after that the elements from general.config are pushed in. Now say here in General.config you say remove `mykey3` which is on your app.config you will see that the final collection has no key as `mykey3`.

In short this is not going to work. Hope this helped you.

Comment: Not true. `general.config` is not a complete config file, it's a common part(section) of a config file, shared by all of my config files.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another config file say Test.config.

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="mykey1" value="New value"/>
</appSettings>
```

and in the app.config appsettings section will look like this

```
<appSettings file="Test.config">
   <add key="mykey1" value="myvalue1"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: But in this case I lost all other items in `general.config`, like `mykey2`.

Comment: @Danny Chen: its working correctly. it only replaces the value of property with key 'mykey1'. and all other values are same as that in the app.config file